# CoreData Background Fetch with Webservice?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I would like to update some data on my device in the background. For example:

Ill got a webservice, which returns me some changes that i need to store into my core data. So my goal is to load the JSON data with Alamofire, loop through all my json objects, and store them into my database. When everything is finished, i would like to update my UI.

The changes could be some hundred rows, so i would like to perform this on the background thread. When ill use:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   var context = appDel.managedObjectContext
   do {
        tasks = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Tasks]
    }
    catch {
        fatalError("Fetching from the store failed")
    }

    for task in tasks {
       // check something here, or set some new values
    }

    // save them in background? But how do i know if save is completed?

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       // update my UI
    }


});
```

Will this all run in background, or do i need multiple contexts here? Ill read somewhere else, that when ill load my managedObjectContext inside a Thread, the whole Fetch runs in background. And how do i know when my context has finished saving, so i can refresh my UITableView?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you do not mean iOS 7 `Background Fetch` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should perform the background code within `context.performBlock {}` instead of `dispatch_async`
2. Call `completionHandler(.NewData)` when you're done

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if i am within the block, everything runs in background? My Webservice Request already runs in background, can i make a performBlock inside a dispatch_async?

Comment: Yes - that runs the code in the background, on the queue associated with your managed object context - which is necessary when dealing with Core Data.

Comment: (`dispatch_async` would use a different queue, which would cause your app to crash when trying to access Core Data objects)